# Implicit list declaration via Python's join method?

Tags: python, list, join, python-3.7

I'm new here, as I'm just starting to program. While trying to learn the basics of Python I'm already running into problems. I hope one of you can help.

I'm having a hard time understanding how this code snippet even works. The list **satz** is being introduced **after** having already been used by the join method above but I'm getting no errors:

```
import random
auswahl = [["Hallo!","Guten Tag!","Moin!"],["Wie geht es Ihnen?","Wie läuft's?", "Whazz uppp?"],["Tschüß!","Auf Wiedersehen!","I'm outta here!"]]
for i in auswahl:
    print (" ".join(satz))
    counter = 0
    satz = []
    for j in i:
        satz.append((auswahl[counter][random.randint(0,2)]))
        counter = counter + 1
```

This is the output:

*Hallo! Wie läuft's? I'm outta here!*

*Moin! Wie geht es Ihnen? Auf Wiedersehen!*

*Guten Tag! Wie geht es Ihnen? Auf Wiedersehen!*

Whereas this example, which uses roughly the same setup doesn't work:

```
counter = [1,2,3]
for i in counter:
    print(" ".join(test))
    test = []

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-ba80e417be84> in <module>()
  1 counter = [1,2,3]
  2 for i in counter:
----> 3     print(" ".join(hallo))
  4     hallo = []

NameError: name 'hallo' is not defined
```

I didn't find anything helpful in the other threads. Maybe one of you can be of help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first code you show will not work either... You must have defined `satz` before you use `join` for the first snippet to not give any errors

Comment: I get the expected error from your first block of code. Did you forget to include some other code?

Comment: Are you executing that code as a script, or in an interactive shell?

Comment: I'm executing both snippets inside a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: @quamrana I'm actually relieved if that's the case. Seeing it work like this did confuse me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to randomize the order of the counter list you need to define test as below:

```
import random
test = []
counter = [1,2,3]
for i in counter: 
    test.append(str(counter[random.randint(0,2)]))
print(" ".join(test))
```

Your first example will not work unless you move `" ".join(satz)` to the bottom of the for loop as `satz` must be defined before it is joined, like so:

```
import random
auswahl = [["Hallo!","Guten Tag!","Moin!"],["Wie geht es Ihnen?","Wie läuft's?", "Whazz uppp?"],["Tschüß!","Auf Wiedersehen!","I'm outta here!"]]
for i in auswahl:
    counter = 0
    satz = []
    for j in i:
        satz.append((auswahl[counter][random.randint(0,2)]))
        counter = counter + 1
    print (" ".join(satz))
```